# Dependent Australian child Deported from Bali to Malaysia as transit

Tags: transit, singapore, australian-citizens, bali, deportation

I failed to renew my son's Visa due forgetfulness. So now he has to be deported but on a 'Blue' stander. (Which he can come back to Indonesia) any time. He is Australian.
Due to Mt Agung Volcano eruption the only flight I can have him on was to transit to KLM then to Singapore then to Aus.

Will this be a problem for him when he arrives in KLM & Singapore?

Please help.

Thanks.
Worried Mum.

Comment: Australian passport holders do not generally require a Singapore visa. How old is your son?

Comment: To clarify, your son was deported from Indonesia?  What is a "Blue stander"?  (KITAS?)

Comment: Is this really relevant to this site ?

Comment: How old is he? If he's under 14 or 15 (maybe 12, depends on the airline), you can ask for airline assistance during the flight and sometimes with transits.